# Validating device configuration with shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Let say `standard.txt` is the standard configuration

And `config.txt` is the config that I would like to validate

Both config contains similar settings, however the config arrangement or formatting might be different a little bit.

```
user@pc:~/$ more standard.txt config.txt 
::::::::::::::
standard.txt
::::::::::::::
ASA-A# show run dns
dns domain-lookup outside
DNS server-group DefaultDNS
    name-server 172.16.51.30 inside
    name-server 8.8.8.8 outside
    name-server 172.16.54.30
    domain-name domain.com
::::::::::::::
config.txt
::::::::::::::
ASA-A# show run dns
dns domain-lookup outside
DNS server-group DefaultDNS
    name-server 172.16.51.30 inside
name-server 172.16.54.30
name-server 8.8.8.8 outside
domain-name domain.com
user@pc:~/$
```

`diff` won't be able to validate it as it will check the formatting as well.

```
user@pc:~/$ diff standard.txt config.txt 
5,7c5,7
<     name-server 8.8.8.8 outside
<     name-server 172.16.54.30
<     domain-name domain.com
---
> name-server 172.16.54.30
> name-server 8.8.8.8 outside
> domain-name domain.com
user@pc:~/$
```

Is there better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Strip whitespaces, sort lines, and then diff (note there is a `-w` option).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe. It's pretty bare, change it to suit your needs:

```
$ awk '               # using awk
{ $1=$1 }             # rebuild records for space control
NR==FNR {             # process file1
    a[$0]             # hash record to a (add counting if multiple identical records)
    next
}
{                     # process file2
    if($0 in a)       # if matching record in file1
        delete a[$0]  # remove from a
    else              # if not found in a
        print"2:",$0  # output record
}
END {                 # in the END
    for(i in a)       # output all records from file1 which had no match
        print "1:",i  # ... in file2
}' file1 file2
```

Output after I changed file1 a bit (well, byte :):

```
2: ASA-A# show run dns
1: ASA-A# show run dnsp
```